# Rails 7 secure API by API key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, api-key, doorkeeper

I'm still fresh in Rails so that question might be trivial.

## Rails app explanation

- Rails 7
- Ruby 3.1.2
- Devise (API and web)

I've got Rails 7 app which is a single page dashboard app with Devise to login users and show data from 3rd party PHP API App. The idea is that PHP APP is sending a POST request to my Rails 7 app to create a user. Under the hood Rails app creates a user and in the response sends `user_id` and `link to reset password` for newly created user - PHP APP uses this link to send it to the user via email (I know, Devise can handle this but that's the requirement). After the user receives the email he can change his password and logging into the Rails app.

## Problem explanation

I want to give ability to create user in Rails app via request POST request made from PHP APP. The issue here is that I'm not sure if I can leave this POST endpoint public. It seems that I am exposing myself to an easy attack. I would like to implement the API Key which will be attached, probably inside headers.

My controller looks super simple:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ActionController::API
  def create
    user = User.new(email: user_params[:email], password: user_params[:password])

    if user.save
      render(json: {
               user: {
                 id: user.id,
                 email: user.email,
                 devise_link: 'some_link',
               },
             })
    else
      render(json: { error: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

I have read a lot, truly a lot of articles on how to set up OAuth or OAuth2 but none of them seem to be suitable for my simple case because I want to protect endpoint for user creation. I tried to use Doorkeeper (which probably will be the best in nearly future for me) but again, provided [docs](https://rubyyagi.com/rails-api-authentication-devise-doorkeeper/#customize-doorkeeper-configuration) example doesn't look like it fits my simple case.

Should I leave this endpoint public or does Rails have some gem that supports my case?

Comment: The naive approach which can get you a long way is to have a "secret" authorization key that you share between the two apps, as in `unless params[:secret] == Rails.credentials.super_secret_key` you reject the creation request. Going further you'd use some kind of crytpographic signing process, but that might be overkill for this use-case. It depends on what your threat vectors are.

Comment: @tadman The Rails App is a kind of microservice for the PHP App so I guess the risk will be low but in other hand PHP App handles, among other things, some payments so it could be sensitive. I'm wondering is such a comparison of secrets at all safe and not considered anti-patern? I've read this post which doesn't really recommend using such approach https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/ms7e4z/comment/gurr23d/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Not disagreeing with that advice, but I did preface that with it being the naive approach, and a place to start. There's some good recommendations there for not storing the key(s) in the database, for sure. A better exchange method doesn't actually send the keys back and forth, just uses public/private key signing, or other mechanisms, but requires a lot more work, like OAuth you mentioned.

Comment: After reading that advice in more depth, I think that largely pertains to having a database full of API keys for a SaaS type service, which makes sense. It applies, to a degree, to authentication between back-end services, not exposed to customers, but if you can keep the key out of your version control, out of your database, and reasonably secured on the server(s), that may be sufficiently secure for your needs. If not, you need to step up and do something better, like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) or a more modern technique.